# How to return an two dimensional array index from a method?

Tags: java, arrays, methods

Im creating a tic tac toe program from here:

http://programmingbydoing.com/a/tic-tac-toe.html

I'm having trouble finding out how to return an array index from a method. I want to user to input 2 integers, ( row, column) and have that index returned and have either char 'O', or 'X' replace the blank corresponding index.

I'm a bit new to java, and am trying to learn it as fast and efficiently as possible to catch up in my class.

```
import java.util.Scanner;

public class ticTacToe{
    public static Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);
    private static int r, c;
    private static char[][] board = new char[3][3];
    //create a 3x3 array of characters

    public static void main( String[] args ) {
        Scanner in = new Scanner(System.in);

        displayBoard();
        do{
            // user inputs two numbers as indexes
            //turn index into "o"
            //prompt other user to make move, repeat with "x"

        }while(checkLoser());

    }

    public static void displayBoard() {
        System.out.println("  0  " + board[0][0] + "|" + board[0][1] + "|" + board[0][2]);
        System.out.println("    --+-+--");
        System.out.println("  1  " + board[1][0] + "|" + board[1][1] + "|" + board[1][2]);
        System.out.println("    --+-+--");
        System.out.println("  2  " + board[2][0] + "|" + board[2][1] + "|" + board[2][2]);
        System.out.println("     0 1 2 ");
    }

    public static int[] getArrayIndex(){
        System.out.println("'O'. Choose your Row...(row, column)");
        int r = in.nextInt();
        int c = in.nextInt();
        return new int[] {r,c};
    }

    public static void userMove(int[][] ){
        board[r][c] = 'O';
    }

    public static boolean checkLoser(){
            if (board[0][0] == board[0][1]){
            if (board [0][1] == board[0][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[1][0] == board[1][1]){
            if (board [1][1] == board[1][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[2][0] == board[2][1]){
            if (board [2][1] == board[2][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[0][0] == board[1][0]){
            if (board [1][0] == board[2][0]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[0][1] == board[1][1]){
            if (board [1][1] == board[1][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[0][2] == board[1][2]){
            if (board [1][2] == board[2][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }

            else if (board[0][0] == board[1][1]){
            if (board [1][1] == board[2][2]){
                return false;
            }
            }
            else if (board[0][2] == board[1][1]){
            if (board [1][1] == board[2][0]){
                return true;
            }
            }else{
                return false;
            }

    }

}
```

Comment: Are you talking about your getArrayIndex() method? If so, what is wrong with the way it is at present?

Comment: Apropos of nothing, you will probably find it easier to program a TicTacToe game using a standard array with 9 elements than using a 2-d array.

Comment: Hi Justin. You've said that you want to __return an array index from a method__. An Array index is just an int, returning the index, from a function in which you are given the index, is simply returning the input to the method. Your description may be confused. 
An array has indices and values
A multidimensional array has values which are also arrays.
`int[][] foo = {{0, 1, 2}, {3, 1, 4}, {1, 1, 2}}` is a 2D array with 9 entries. When accessing a value in a 2D array, i.e. `foo[1][2]` you are referencing first, the array at index 1 of foo[], and then the int at index 2 of `foo[1]`, which is 4

Answer (score 3):

The Java-way to do this is define a class to hold the row and column index.

```
final class BoardIndex {

    final int row;
    final int col;

    BoradIndex(final int r, final int c) {
        this.row = r;
        this.col = c;
    }
}
```

You can then return it from a function.

```
BoardIndex getIt() {
    return new BoradIndex(1, 2);
}
```

It's quite a bit of typing but many Java folks prefer this kind of being explicit about types over using, say, an array of integers.

Comment: Generally I agree, but this class in isolation won't do much for a beginner like the OP seems to be.

Comment: @Robert I must admit that I have somewhat rushed into posting this answer without really understanding what is it that the OP “is having trouble with”.  So I'm not sure what to add to my answer to make it more useful.  More info by the OP would be helpful.

Answer (score 1):

Well, to answer your question, since it's a two-dimensional array, you obviously need two indices to be returned (as you probably thought). Since a function can only return one Object, as you correcty meant to do given your function:

```
public static int[] getArrayIndex(){
        System.out.println("'O'. Choose your Row...(row, column)");
        int r = in.nextInt();
        int c = in.nextInt();
        return new int[] {r,c};
    }
```

you returned a two-element array with both the indices you need. That is ONE way you can accomplish it. Other forms include creating an Object with two int elements and using it instead or storing both variables in the same int somehow (keeping them one digit long for example).
Anyways, your way to returning those indices is alright. How you use that information is up to you then. I guess you'd have to store it in a temporary int array like this `int[] temp=getArrayIndex();` and then access each element to get the corresponding indices.

However, your code has other errors, like forgetting to put a name to the parameter in this function (or the fact that such parameter isn't used anyways):

```
public static void userMove(int[][] ){
    board[r][c] = 'O';
}
```

I suggest you check on those. Maybe the program you compiled gave you an error and you thought it was because of the `new int[] {r,c}` thing, but naaah, that works. If that's the case, check the rest, it's something else. I'll be glad to help though, so feel free to ask. ^^

Answer (score 0):

you may want to consider using java.awt.Point.