# How can I get the indexes of an object in a multidimensional array?

Tags: java, multidimensional-array, indices

Suppose I have a multidimensional array of object

`Object[][][] obj=new Object[10][10][10];`

filled with objects of any kind. Is there a method

`public ArrayList(Integer) getIndices(Object o)`

taking as input an object and giving me back the indices of the object?
I don't care about the actual class of my multidimensional array: you can substitute `Object` with another class of your choice. I don't even care about the type of the output: it can be an `array` of `int`, or an `ArrayList(Integer)`, or whatever you want. Finally I don't care whether this method throws exceptions when the input object doesn't lie in the 3D-matrix. 
I just want to understand what methods are there that do more or less what I want.

Is there such a method? If not, how can I define it? The only way that I can think of is to iterate on the entries of the 3D-matrix and to check manually with `.equals`. Is this the fastest way (even with large matrices)?

Thank you in advance

P.S. I checked older questions like [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/27236568/how-to-return-an-two-dimensional-array-index-from-a-method) but it didn't help.

Comment: With indexing, a triple loop to find the object. This would be `O(a * b * c)` - where `a`,`b` and `c` are the sizes of the dimensions.

Comment: *Is this the fastest way?*: it's the only way.

Comment: Thank you, I was just wondering if a better method could be defined, but I understand this is not the case

Comment: If you want a better efficiency you have to spend additional memory: Maintain a reverse set that maps object -> int[] (indices). That works of course only if an object is not present more that one time in your matrix. Or you could add some fields to your `Object` that saves the index.

Answer (score -1):

You can use this method to do so..

```
  private static void find_indices(int[][][] arr,int row, int col, int height, int value) {
    ArrayList<String> list = new ArrayList<>();
    for (int i = 0; i < row; i++) {
        for (int j = 0; j < col; j++) {
            for (int k = 0; k < height; k++) {
                if (arr[i][j][k] == value) {
                    list.add(String.valueOf(i));
                    list.add(String.valueOf(j));
                    list.add(String.valueOf(k));
                    list.add(String.valueOf("\n"));
                }
            }
        }
    }
    for (int i = 0; i < list.size(); i++) {
        System.out.print(list.get(i));
    }
}
```

call it using `find_indices(arr, value);`

This is a working code in my all standard application. You can put the above method in any util class and use it by sending array and value as parameters. I have used list here so that if multiple objects are found at different indices than it will give all the indices.
Keep Coding :)

Comment: Once found you can `return`. No need to carry on searching. Also - it's better to `return` some useful value rather than printing to the console - maybe an `int[3]`? Why are you using an `ArrayList<String>` to store the result? The OP already describes this perfectly - I do not think this post adds anything apart from a poor implementation of the thing the OP said they **didn't** want to do...

Comment: Also, just noticed it assumes that the array is not jagged - really you need to do `arr[i].length` and `arr[i][j].length`.

Comment: This is exactly what I do not want to do. If i have to search in each entry of my matrix, then I can just check with `obj[i][j][k].equals(o)` (because despite what you write, I was dealing with objects, not only integers) and then return the indices I've found without saving or printing them..

Comment: There's no other option. I have printed it for closing the method. You can return it or anything else you want. But i have searched a lot while doing this in my application and got this as the only way.
Secondly, list is used if multiple objects of same element is present.
Thirdly, return type can be changed or made generic. No Big Deal.